# How to obfuscate Android library project with Eclipse?

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, android-library

Hi I developed one small library in Java for my Android application. I want to do obfuscating for that library. I using Android version 4.1.2. First thing is that according to Google's Android documentation there is no `proguard.cfg` file in my project root directory. Instead of that `proguard-project.txt` is there. I add `proguard.config=proguard-project.txt` into my `project-properties` file.

After this configuration I tried to export this library project and try to do obfuscating of that project. It showing error can generate .apk file because it is library project. 
Then I tried with another option in export. Instead of regular `export android application` I use `general -> archive file` and tried to export it and generate jar file but I check inside the jar and no encoding is done. That means anyone can extract and check classes and content inside my library. But the main thing is that it generates proguard folder inside my project and also generate `dump mapping seeds usage.text` files inside it.

So I need help to do proper ProGuard obfuscating of my Android library. Am I doing something wrong. What kind of configuration do I have to add inside my `proguard-project.txt` so that it will do proper encoding of my code?

Comment: proguard doesn't obfuscate library projects

Comment: Thank you pankaj for replay. Then how to obfuscate library projects in android. Need Help Thank you.

Comment: Hey, actually I don't have solution for that. So I can't help you for this. hope u will get answer from another SO

Comment: Thank you pankaj for replay.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can obfuscate a library project, but **not directly!** You can only do that by exporting the entire application's project that uses that library.

With that in mind, you can set a different `proguard.cfg` at the [root folder](http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements) of your Library Project.

Hope this helps.